# push commits on branch, GITHUB

Tags: git, github

Недавно работаю с гитом. Склонировал себе на ПК репозиторий
Там должно быть две ветки на двоих людей, включая меня. Главная ветка main(там работает мой начальник) и вторая - моя - Ivan-develop.
Когда я складировал репозиторий себе на ПК я столкнулся с проблемой, что не было ветки Ivan-develop. Была только main. Но я нашёл решение в инете: нужно сделать такую штуку --> `git checkout --track -b Ivan-develop  origin/Ivan-develop`

Все сработало, но теперь я хочу на свою ветку перенести все актуальные изменения с ветки main. с помощью команды `git merge main` у меня все получилось.
А вот теперь главный вопрос! Далее когда я хочу запушить все на удалённый репозиторий, я пишу `git push -u origin Ivan-develop` у меня такая вот ошибка: `remote: Permission to Devy707/Back-Front-Iddly.git denied to ivanhulak. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Devy707/Back-Front-Iddly.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403` и я не знаю, что мне делать и как решить данную проблему. Может кто сталкивался с этим помогите пожалуйста!!! Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: слишком много ненужной информации, можно было проще написать: хочу залить изменения на удалённый репозиторий и получаю ошибку `текст ошибки`

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что владелец репозитория должен в настройках гитхаба дать права. Также, убедись, что пароль верный.